# Solution-specific Visual Studio settings

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, resharper

I'm working on a several projects with several teams.

One team uses Hg, one Git the other uses Subversion.
One team uses spaces, other team uses tabs.

Is there a way i could change this settings based on a solution i'm using?

For example, if I'm using a.sln i wanna use source control plugin VisualSVN and use spaces. When i open b.sln i want to use a Git provider and tabs.

Is there a way i could achieve this automatically?

I'm using VS2015 so i'm open for any VS add-ins. Also i use Resharper so i'm open any suggestions to achieve this with reshaper's help.

I have already tried method described in 
[Change source control plug-in in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16249595/change-source-control-plug-in-in-visual-studio), [How to specify the source control plugin on a per-solution basis in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307824/how-to-specify-the-source-control-plugin-on-a-per-solution-basis-in-visual-studi),

I found this https://github.com/ceztko/SccAutoSwitcher but i haven't been able to get it working.

I found the https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-visualstudio#readme but this solves only a part of my needs.

thanks for any info

Answer (score 1):

Might try [Visual Studio Hives (“Instances”)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Each "hive" is an isolated VS configuration, as if you got several separate VS installations of the same version on one machine. Each one with its own settings, extensions, and all.

To try, just run VS with `devenv.exe /RootSuffix HiveNameHere`

Newer VS versions got a bug that per-machine extensions are not isolated within hives, but that can also be worked around if really needed. So you could even have different source control plugins installed in different hives.

R# will share its settings between all VS versions and hives though. But there you can change any setting value on per-solution level.