# SVN to Git change not working in visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, azure-devops

I have an application that was written in .NET framework. I have recently moved my source code from SVN to GIT and am using Azure DevOps.

1. I go to a branch in Azure DevOps
2. Clone the repo to Visual Studio 2019
3. VS opens, but there is no menu option with the name "Git". This is because my VS thinks I still use SVN as my version control.
4. when I go to tools options and change the version control plugin to Git, it throws a warning message and closes the Project.
5. At this point I see the Git menu option, but the solution is closed. So I don't see anything in my solution explorer.
6. When I go to Git Changes menu, it seem to show the changes correctly but that is of no use if I don't see anything in my solution explorer.

This is been a pain and I don't know how to resolve it. ??!

Comment: Is there an `.svn` directory in the project when you clone it?

Comment: What method did you use to migrate git？ Have you use the method from [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/perform-migration-from-svn-to-git?view=azure-devops) ?  Please refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16249677/13464420 you could check your project sln file settings.

Comment: You can aslo share some screenshots about the issues in Visual Studio and the Repo content. This will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. I will try this and keep you guys posted.